# WhatsApp Bot Using whatsapp-web.js Stuck at 'Starting - node index.js'

Tags: node.js, axios, bots, puppeteer, whatsapp

[error_demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpD5O.jpg)

I'm developing a Node.js WhatsApp bot using `whatsapp-web.js` in Visual Studio Code, and I'm encountering a problem where my bot gets stuck at the "starting" phase. Here are some key details:

- I'm using `whatsapp-web.js` to send HTTP requests via WhatsApp Web.
- The bot works as expected locally on my computer when I run it.
- However, recently, it has started to get stuck at the "starting" phase with the following error:

```
[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
```

**My local environment details:**

- Node.js version: `18.16.1`
- NPM version: `9.8.1`
- I'm not deploying this on Heroku or any external server; it's running locally on my computer.
- The issue occurs seemingly randomly and wasn't present initially.

**My Depedencies**

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "puppeteer": "^20.8.3",
    "qrcode-terminal": "^0.12.0",
    "whatsapp-web.js": "^1.21.1-alpha.1"
```

I have posted the source code of my bot in my github's repository
[NythAI-GEN2](https://github.com/fromrha/NythAI-GEN2)

I've tried:

- Restarting Visual Studio Code and my computer.
- Ensuring my Node.js and NPM versions are up-to-date.
- Checking my code for any recent changes that might have caused this issue.
- Starting from the beginning with just `!ping` and `pong` feature
- Tried using 3 different wifi
- Starting from `npm run dev` and `node index.js`

I'm uncertain why this issue occured recently. because it literally working fine before. Has anyone experienced a similar problem when developing WhatsApp bots with `whatsapp-web.js` locally?

Any insights or troubleshooting steps would be appreciated. Thanks!